# How to store multiple values of a same category in SQL using JAVA Spring orJhipster

Tags: sql, spring, apache-poi, dto, jhipster

I need to write a java code that stores the following in SQL with a single submit button.

[image]

I need to retrieve names from another table (employees) and display in the UI and then I have to get inputs ( Salary, Department, Manager) from the user and then I have to store each row into a Table (salary_Details) in SQL.

As per my understandig I can write DTO class as following

```
private String name1;
private String salary1;
private String department1;
private String manager1;
```

But I am not sure about the total number of employees in the employees table.

1. How can i achieve this using JAVA Spring?
2. How to write DTO class for the UI page to store values?
3. Is there any alternative way to do this?

**Note: I am using Jhipster to develop my project, If there is a way to handle this in Jhipster, please let me know.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Comment: I have tried anything but wat i ca do is creating a DTO like this..                                    private String name1;
private String salary1;
private String department1;
private String manager1;

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer finally.

Using MapStruct can help in achieving this feat.

```
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {

Set<String> integerSetToStringSet(Set<Integer> integers);

List<EmployeeDto> employeessToEmployeeDtos(List<Employee> employees);

EmployeeDto employeeToEmployeeDto(Employees employees);
```

}

Please have a look at this link.
https://iamhug.gitbooks.io/mapstruct/content/6mapping_collections.html